Какой знак препинания должен стоять перед союзом И в данном предложении?
Учитывается зарплата жены - 100 рублей и мужа - 200 рублей.

Правильно:
Учитывается зарплата жены — 100 рублей и мужа — 200 рублей.
Розенталь, § 19. Обособленные приложения

При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире. Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:


для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения:

Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её (М. Г.).

Вообще, русский язык достаточно гибок для того, чтобы у вас имелись варианты. Опишу вам два, которые исходят из разных точек зрения, но обе теоретически правильные.
Вариант 1

Учитывается зарплата жены — 100 рублей — и мужа — 200 рублей.

Логика тут проста: в предложении «Учитывается зарплата жены и мужа» есть вставная конструкция «100 рублей», выделяемая с двух сторон тире.
Недостаток данного варианта — это изобилие длинных тире, превращающих предложение в пульс покойника.
Где-то рядом с местами обитания людей, не освоивших программу русского языка в школе, водятся еретики, считающие, что во вставных конструкциях хватает одного длинного тире, но всерьёз рассматривать подобное не вижу смысла.
Вариант 2
Он мне нравится больше. Мы делим предложение на две грамматические основы: «Учитывается зарплата жены» и «Учитывается зарплата мужа», но во втором мы опускаем главные члены — подлежащее и сказуемое, — оставляя только «и мужа».
В итоге вторую грамматическую основу мы понимаем из контекста, а предложение изящно делится запятой на основании правил расстановки знаков препинания в сложносочинённом предложении:

Учитывается зарплата жены — 100 рублей, и мужа — 200 рублей.


Хм, тогда много где можно подразумевать основы и мысленно их добавлять. Например: В саду росли кустарники и деревья. Можно трактовать так: В саду росли кустарники, и (в саду росли) деревья. Но это как-то странно и неправильно)

@ЛюдмилаПетрикова Да, можно. И неправильного здесь ничего нет. Два года назад разбирали отрывок из "Иерусалима" Мура. Там переводчик успешно этим пользовался

В саду росли кустарники, и деревья. Так правильно?!

@ЛюдмилаПетрикова Правильно как автор решит. Если нужно, сделает отдельной грамматической основой, предложением или абзацем. Зависит от того, насколько вам важно выделить "деревья"

Допустим. Но о каких еретиках вы толкуете? О Розентале?

А что допустим? Читайте про присоединиельные союзы "А Рудин заговорил о самолюбии, и очень дельно заговорил (Т.)." "Люди часто посмеиваются над ним, и справедливо [посмеиваются] (Пан.)." В том числе у вашего Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120

Допустим, вы меня убедили.

Называть еретиком человека и ссылаться на него же, чтобы подкрепить свою правоту, - это лицемерие.

@ЛюдмилаПетрикова Я не помню, чтобы уполномочивал вас проецировать мои тезисы на кого бы то ни было. И, думаю, права переходить на личности вам тоже на этом форуме не предоставляли.

Ничего страшного)

Учитываются зарплаты жены — 100 руб. и мужа — 200 руб. (Одна основа и перечисление).
Учитывается зарплата жены — 100 руб., и мужа — 200 руб. (Две основы и соед. союз и в качестве присоединительного а также).
